# Headers-first sync and malicious peers

Tags: security, synchronization, block-header, peers, verification

Since headers-first syncing specifies that the entire header chain is downloaded from a single peer, how does the downloading node know that it is not being served a manufactured out-of-consensus header chain? Does it perform any cross referencing against other peers? What is the exact mechanism used here?